# Array and List length isn't as initialized

Tags: arrays, .net, vb.net, size

Okay, I'm very confused. I code for quite some time now and have never seen this.

When I create an array in `VB.NET` like this

```
Dim arr(2) as Object
```

and then fetch myself the length (either debugger or code), it returns `3`.
When I create an array with length `0`, its size is `1`.

The same happens, when I create a List (new List(1) -> count:`2`)

How does this make sense. I have never seen this kind of behavior in any other language before ...

Does anyone have an explanation for this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#? i think the most important thing at the moment is working out what language you are in. Also this would have been answered instantly by reading the documentation

Comment: In C#, for `List<T>` we have constructor called`List<T>(Int32)` where parameter `Int32` is for capacity. If you create instance of List with capacity 2 like `List<int> listInt = new List<int>(2);` then `listInt.Capacity` will give you result as 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the answer in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)

> When you use Visual Basic syntax to define the size of an array, you
>   specify its highest index, not the total number of elements in the
>   array.

`Dim arr(2)` creates an array with 2 as last index, which means 3 places for indices 0-2.

Comment: The language you were asking about was very important because in C# it is the number of elements.

Comment: @Mary Yea, I come from C# and, tbh, thougth, because both languages are .NET, that they work similar in this regard.

Comment: @DaedraEYE Don't feel stupid! They should be the same but vb programmers had enough to deal with moving from vb6. Changing array declarations would break old code. In the pre List(Of T) days there were a lot of arrays. Now we can all use List(Of T) an avoid the conflict.